# Getting min of a range given number in range and range min/max increment

Tags: math, lua, range, max, min

I have a range that increments in steps of 80. For example, `min_1=0 max_1=80, min_2=80 max_2=160` etc. Now say I have a number that for case one is `n_1 = 47` and then for case two `n_2 = 111`. For both cases, each number falls in a separate incremented range. Is there in an easy way to figure the min of the range for each number? For case one the min of the range would be `0` and for case two it would be `80`.

I'm sorry if this is simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Thank you for any help! Also, I use Lua if anyone wants to type in an answer in that but it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `integer modulo` operator:

```
 low_end_of_range = value - (value % 80)
```

Is available (not sure for Lua) , you can use also `integer division` (`div, //`) operator:

```
 low_end_of_range = (value div 80) * 80
```

Comment: Lua does have the `integer modulo operator` (also `%` in Lua), but does not have the `integer division operator`.

Comment: OK, so the second approach is for reference for another languages.

Comment: Actually, Lua 5.3 does have integer division, written `a // b`. For Lua 5.2 and 5.1, `math.floor(a / b)` works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Please take a look MBo's answer. I actually think it will be less computationally expensive and is thus a better solution than this one.**

You can do this with the `math.floor()` function. Let me explain.

First of all, look at the following calculations:

- `47/80 = 0.5875`
- `111/80 = 1.3875`
- `163/80 = 2.0375`

If you could just round down each of those numbers, you would end up with `0`, `1`, and `2` respectively. You could then take those numbers and multiply each by `80`, resulting in `0`, `80`, and `160` respectively.

So how exactly do you do this "rounding down"? You use `math.floor()`:

```
number = math.floor(56.87)
print(number) --prints 56
```

Putting this all together, your code will look something like this:

```
number = 111
increment = 80

min_range = math.floor(number/increment) * increment
```

This is actually a common problem: for example, how do you round a number down to the nearest tenth's place or thousands place? You simply find its "minimum range" given an increment of `.1` (tenth's place) or `1000` (thousands place).

So that you know, there is another function for rounding up called `math.ceil()`. They are called `math.floor()` and `math.ceil` because rounding down is like "flooring" the number, and rounding up like like "ceiling-ing" the number.